# Static function pointer member in a class template

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

How can I use a static function pointer member in my class template?

I'm working with C++ in Visual Studio, and my code looks similar to the following:

```
template<typename T>
class ClassTemplate
{
public:
    static T* CallIt() { return ClassTemplate<T>::mFunctionPointer(); }

private:
    static T* (*mFunctionPointer)();
};
```

When I compile I get an "unresolved external symbol" error. I think I'm supposed to do something like this outside of the class declaration:

```
template<typename T>
T* (ClassTemplate<T>::*mFunctionPointer)() = NULL;
```

Unfortunately then I get C2998, "cannot be a template definition".

Any ideas?

Comment: Not that this solves your compiler error, but remember that templates + headers don't mix so well.  You have to include the implementation in every translation unit that you are using the template in.

Comment: Thanks Merlyn, but I do have everything in my header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the position of the `*` so that it's

```
template<typename T>
T* (*ClassTemplate<T>::mFunctionPointer)() = NULL;
```

otherwise you are trying to define a namespace-level variable `mFunctionPointer` as a pointer-to-member of class `ClassTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your definition to this:

```
template<typename T>
T* (*ClassTemplate<T>::mFunctionPointer)() = NULL;
```

The * should appear before the identifier (including class scope resolution).